# How to integrate EF Core 2.1.0 in .Net Framework 4.7.2 project

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to add EF Core 2.1 into my .Net Framework 4.7.2 project but on runtime, I'm getting an exception that it is not able to find these libraries but they are a part of .NETStandard 2.0. I tried to add all manually(I don't think it is the correct solution).

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory (>= 2.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 2.0.0)
Remotion.Linq (>= 2.1.1)
System.Collections.Immutable (>= 1.4.0)
System.ComponentModel.Annotations (>= 4.4.0)
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (>= 4.4.1)
System.Interactive.Async (>= 3.1.1)
```

But the following exception is really weird and I don't know hot to solve it. System.Security.AccessControl is a apart of System.Data.
*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.*

So, my main question is should I be able to use EF Core 2.1.0 in .Net Framework 4.7.2 project? If yes, should I manually add these dlls into my project?

Comment: Are you using the nuget for EF Core? It should add everything you need.

Comment: Yes, I used nuget and installed Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.Design, Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.Relational and Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.Tools. Should I include anything else?

Comment: The nuget should auto-add everything you need.

Comment: I also thought so, but it didn't and I will try to start over. Thanks

Comment: @chsharpgirl Just done a test on .NET 4.7.1 . I've written `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in the nuget console and the Visual Studio auto-added all the dependancies

Comment: Check if you have to update the nuget component of visual studio (click on the flag in the upper right side of the title bar of visual studio)

Comment: Well, in a brand new project it worked out, but we are migrating our existing project to ef core 2.1 and I see this odd behavior only there. I want to keet EF 6.2 and have also referenced to ef core. Something went wrong on this path.

Comment: @csharpgirl I am trying to repro this and as you said, on a brand new project, I couldn't. Did you upgrade an existing project that was targeting a previous version of .NET Framework to target .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: @csharpgirl I tried upgrading projects from 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7.0, and 4.7.1 to 4.7.2 after installing the EF Core packages. 

I got some errors due to differences in the .NET Standard 2.0 implementations: some versions require redirects are required that are generated at package installation time (you can uninstall the package and install it again after upgrading to solve this). However, my errors don't mention System.Security.AccessControl. Could you please report an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/entityframeworkcore/issues/new including more details about your project?